# format date to rfc 822 in groovy

Tags: date, groovy, format, rfc822

i´m having troubles generating a valid  tag in a rss2.0 xml document

I´m using this code

```
 pubDate(review.dtCreated.format('EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z'))
```

it results in

```
<pubDate>Di, 21 Mai 2013 16:48:28 +0200</pubDate>
```

---

that looks correct for me but w3c-feed validator says

```
 pubDate must be an RFC-822 date-time: Di, 21 Mai 2013 16:48:28 +0200
```

on the help page they have an example :

```
<pubDate>Wed, 02 Oct 2002 15:00:00 +0200</pubDate>
```

---

did i look too long on the screen or is there really a diferrence between my formatted date and the feed-validator´s example ?=

how to get this correct ?

for any hint thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it in an English Locale:

```
pubDate( new java.text.SimpleDateFormat( 'EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z', Locale.US ).format( review.dtCreated ) )
```

---

According to [the RFC](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822.txt), `Di` is not allowed as a day name:

> 5 .  DATE AND TIME SPECIFICATION
>
> ```
>  5.1.  SYNTAX
>
>  date-time   =  [ day "," ] date time        ; dd mm yy
>                                              ;  hh:mm:ss zzz
>
>  day         =  "Mon"  / "Tue" /  "Wed"  / "Thu"
>              /  "Fri"  / "Sat" /  "Sun"
>
>  date        =  1*2DIGIT month 2DIGIT        ; day month year
>                                              ;  e.g. 20 Jun 82
>
>  month       =  "Jan"  /  "Feb" /  "Mar"  /  "Apr"
>              /  "May"  /  "Jun" /  "Jul"  /  "Aug"
>              /  "Sep"  /  "Oct" /  "Nov"  /  "Dec"
> ```